# Get data-* attribute of the selected <option>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the second value of an option tag using document.get.elementbyId.

```html
<select id="test" class="form-control">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1" data-doj="20-06-2011">John</option>
  <option value="2" data-doj="10-05-2015">Clif</option>
  <option value="3" data-doj="01-01-2008">Alexander</option>
</select>
```

Usually, I would use `document.getElementById("test").value;` to get the value of one option. What should I do if I have multiple values like in this case? `document.getElementById("test").data-doj;`?
Thank you.

Comment: there's an [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to access `data-*` attributes, you may check out the example for your use case [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61247406/11299053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the working example below, How you can get value, text and custom attribute of selected option -

```js
function trackValue(){ 
var element = document.getElementById("test");
var option_value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
var option_text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
var option_doj = element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-doj')
console.log('value-', option_value);
console.log('text-', option_text);
console.log('doj-', option_doj);
}
```

```html
<select id="test" class="form-control" onChange="trackValue();">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="1"  data-doj="20-06-2011">John</option>
<option value="2"  data-doj="10-05-2015">Clif</option>
<option value="3"  data-doj="01-01-2008">Alexander</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

> The HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex is a long that reflects the index of the first or last selected  element, depending on the value of multiple. The value -1 indicates that no element is selected.

To access `data-*` attributes, use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Note - `this` in event-handler refers to the element on an event is invoked.

```js
let select = document.getElementById("test");
select.onchange = function() {
  let selectedI = this.selectedIndex;
  console.log(this.options[selectedI].dataset.doj)
};
```

```html
<select id="test" class="form-control">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1" data-doj="20-06-2011">John</option>
  <option value="2" data-doj="10-05-2015">Clif</option>
  <option value="3" data-doj="01-01-2008">Alexander</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

navigate using selectedIndex

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("change",function() {
  const opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  console.log(opt.value, 
    opt.getAttribute("data-doj"),  // or opt.dataset.doj
    opt.text)
})
```

```html
<select id="test" class="form-control">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1" data-doj="20-06-2011">John</option>
  <option value="2" data-doj="10-05-2015">Clif</option>
  <option value="3" data-doj="01-01-2008">Alexander</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, no one still suggested.

There's a way to access `HTMLCollection` of the selected options with [`HTMLSelecteElement.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions). If you have only one `<option>` selected at a time, you may simply pull its first element (with `[0]`).

To access `data-*` attribute there's a [proper API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), which implies `.dataset['propertyname']` kind of syntax:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function(){
  const [selectedOption] = this.selectedOptions,
        dataDoj = selectedOption.dataset.doj
  console.log(dataDoj)        
})
```

```html
<select id="test" class="form-control">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="1"  data-doj="20-06-2011">John</option>
<option value="2"  data-doj="10-05-2015">Clif</option>
<option value="3"  data-doj="01-01-2008">Alexander</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Never seen this.selectedOptions[0] before. New to me :) Not working in IE

Comment: As long as 10% of my users use it, I am afraid yes. We have more IE11 visitors than Edge